# loading TProfile in Uproot issue getting y-values

Tags: uproot

I have trouble loading y-values from a TProfile object from my .root file.

It seems using file.pandas() loads only the x-values, the counts and variances but not the specific y-values.

I have tried file.values also, which returns counts, but not y-values

Answer (score 0):

Objects read from ROOT files have a Pythonic interpretation only if "methods" have been included in uproot-methods. `TProfile` has not been handled in this way—the only reason anything works for you is because `TProfile` is a subclass of `TH1`, and `TH1` has a `.pandas()` method. Since `TH1` is for one-dimensional histograms, it doesn't include code that would handle a second dimension.

uproot-methods is user contributed. If you want `TProfile` methods, you can add one here and submit a pull request:

https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot-methods/tree/master/uproot_methods/classes

If you add a `TProfile` module containing a `Methods` class here, uproot will automatically load it and apply it to the `TProfile` objects it loads from ROOT files.

For any class, even those we haven't heard of, uproot loads all of the private member data into a Python object. You'll find all of your `TProfile` data in attributes that start with `_f`, such as `_fSumw2` and `_fBinEntries`. The methods just use these "internal" attributes to present a more user-friendly picture of the data, such as Pandas.

Here's an example of getting data from an uninterpreted `TProfile`:

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> import uproot
>>> 
>>> file = uproot.open("http://scikit-hep.org/uproot/examples/hepdata-example.root")
>>> hprof = file["hprof"]
>>> 
>>> numpy.sqrt(numpy.array(hprof._fSumw2) / numpy.array(hprof._fBinEntries))
```

will print

```
-c:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
array([18.00160401, 17.08522023, 16.98982401, 15.18948269, 13.73788834,
       13.37976188, 13.55597897, 12.66036748, 12.68400763, 11.86598111,
       11.69668773, 11.64276616, 10.08540753, 10.15367219,  9.76541727,
        8.84047502,  8.73065944,  8.24346727,  7.46907584,  7.6620407 ,
        7.09749961,  6.62763951,  6.42199904,  5.98234406,  5.78193984,
        5.14476043,  5.15432392,  4.715674  ,  4.50246509,  4.36212988,
        3.86741244,  3.80635409,  3.60625837,  3.29332404,  3.04594764,
        2.98292569,  2.74283755,  2.50385849,  2.50978034,  2.30446027,
        2.29145554,  2.18459822,  1.99270465,  1.92651016,  1.86253428,
        1.79821825,  1.807856  ,  1.80803939,  1.75249321,  1.81588997,
        1.8226282 ,  1.74867267,  1.79842962,  1.75790778,  1.70895758,
        1.859834  ,  1.82793384,  1.96163584,  1.81903189,  2.0223054 ,
        2.14521968,  2.24565426,  2.24184203,  2.48460961,  2.63208939,
        2.69851588,  2.98989799,  3.1141892 ,  3.25304525,  3.46517157,
        3.53320406,  3.98586013,  4.25062225,  4.57520817,  4.75338005,
        5.18494724,  5.387066  ,  5.6277353 ,  5.8802666 ,  6.34427442,
        6.51966721,  7.24680462,  7.33759813,  7.63198011,  8.34535604,
        9.30064575,  8.82698396,  9.4099613 ,  9.60905376, 10.31570735,
       11.17540473, 11.13947421, 12.78232904, 12.1993165 , 12.39763587,
       16.68535354, 13.30451531, 14.67711301, 14.96741772,         nan,
       18.32199478, 17.84275258])
```

which are the y-values for this `TProfile`. The errors on those values are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The TProfile y-values (`h`) and default errors (`err`) can be reconstructed using the private member data according to

```
import numpy
import uproot 

file = uproot.open("somefile_w_TProfile.root")
hprof = file['hprof_title']

cont = numpy.array(hprof.values)
sumw = numpy.array(hprof._fBinEntries)[1:-1]
err2 = numpy.array(hprof._fSumw2)[1:-1]

h = cont/sumw
s = numpy.sqrt(err2/sumw - h**2)
err = s/numpy.sqrt(sumw)
```

N.B.  The C++ TProfile member `.fArray` is called `.values` in the uproot TProfile object.